# TryXXX-like methods with "out" parameters vs returning a nullable value type?

Tags: c#, nullable, out

I often see methods like this in C#: (doing a computation that may or may not give a result)

```
bool TrySomething(SomeType inputData, out SomeOtherType result) { ... }
```

Why people don't use instead something like this?

```
Nullable<SomeOtherType> TrySomething(SomeType inputData) { ... }
```

Is it just performance difference?
This is a `struct`, so there must be no heap allocation, right?
Or I have missed something?

Comment: Sometimes `null` is a valid value and not a sign of failure...?

Comment: Especially in case of int.TryParse, DateTime.TryParse and other

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thought about this, but then this can be also reflected in the type of SomeOtherType? We can substitute SomeOtherType with `Nullable<SomeThirdType>`, for example.

Comment: The most obvious problem is that this only works if `SomeOtherType` is a struct.

Comment: @Lee seems like the most realistic explanation. But can be Nullable<T> extended to support both classes and structs while keeping its performance characteristics?

Comment: `Nullable<T>` is illegal (cannot be constructed) if `T` is a reference type or itself a `Nullable<>`.

Comment: @SargeBorsch - `Nullable<T>` requires that `T` be a struct, so you can't use it with reference types. You could create your own `Option<T>` struct type without that constraint, and return that. The main issue with that approach is that it adds yet another way of representing a missing value, along with `Nullable<T>` for structs and `null` for reference types.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I went checking this out...("or itself a Nullable<>") looks like strange limitation to me.

Comment: Here's the "converse" question: "Sometimes a method will just use the default value of a type as a return value. Why not use the try-get pattern? For example the Linq extension `.FirstOrDefault()` can be bad with a sequence of `int`s because we cannot tell if the sequence was empty or just started with `0`. They could give us a `bool`-returning `.TryGetFirst(out i)` extension instead."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nullable` was introduced - like generics - in C# 2.0. There is a lot of code that predates that.

And to be honest, I am not a big fan of just returning a `Nullable` whenever something can go wrong.

What you usually have is a method like

```
SomeOtherType Something(SomeType inputData) { ... }
```

which will throw an exception if something goes wrong. Now in some cases, you want to avoid an exception, so there is an alternative way: the one you gave.

```
bool TrySomething(SomeType inputData, out SomeOtherType result) { ... }
```

However, an exception is precise in what went wrong, a boolean value isn't. So if it gives you `false`, you have little more information that "It didn't work". In some cases, that might be enough. Me, I like to distinguish a "My collection did not contain that value" error from a "I am currently running out of memory and cannot do anything anymore" error, or whatever else.

Now introducing the `Nullable` as return value, it is - as I call it - druid knowledge to know that receiving `null` doesn't mean "The value is null", but "Some error occurred". That is something you would need to document and explain, while the `bool` result of a `TryXXX` method is self-explanatory.

In short, you gain nothing but produce slightly more confusing code by using `Nullable` as a return value.

Comment: Not absolutely nothing. When using `out` parameters, you must first declare a variable for storing the result.

Comment: And when using the `Nullable` method result, you need to store it in a variable, to check it for `null` before usage. Nothing gained.

Comment: There is null coalescing operator that sometimes allows to simplify this. Also, the assignment is done with 1 statement, not 2.

Comment: Never use one statement that needs explanation, when two would lead to self-explanatory code. As a programmer, you are not paid for most functionalíty compressed in as little characters as possible. You are paid for correct, easily understandable, easily manageable, easily maintainable code.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But why it is considered easier? What's hard with Nullable<T>? And also I want to pay attention that I wrote about statements, not characters. Less statements makes code structurally simpler, while less characters not.

Comment: Structurally simpler does NOT always mean easier to understand. And "hard" about `Nullable<T>` is the fact that `null` is usually a correct value. You are redefining it to mean error. This is counterintuitive, you have to document this, and so on and so forth.