# TryParse dilemma-Dealing with out parameters

Tags: c#, functional-programming, out

I never liked `out` and `ref` parameters.When I see them in action they give me a feeling that something is messy about the design.

I thought that the only exception was the so called TryXXX pattern that returns a boolean as the function result (whether everything was fine or something went wrong) and an out parameter for the real result, until I read [this article](http://luketopia.net/2014/02/05/fsharp-and-output-parameters/) today and It made me think if there's a better pattern to implement this kind of methods.

I thought that we could either have a function that returns more than one result(or as the article says a tuple)

```
Tuple<Exception,T> TryParseT(object obj)
```

or a function that accepts a callback function for success :

```
void TryParseT(object obj,Action<T> success)
```

The question is , which one is better from a functional design point of view ?

**UPDATE :**
To rephrase my question , I want to know which of these two functions more complies with Functional Programming principles and why ?

Comment: Doesn't get more opinion based then this. I'd go with the nullable approach myself.

Comment: The approach I've taken is to have an `Option<T>` class that is returned from various parsers. It then returns `None` or the value. Take a look at https://github.com/DavidArno/SuccincT/tree/master/SuccincT/BasicTypesParsers for more details.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov. Null is evil. Please don't encourage its spread.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I considered nullable approach until I saw this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505958/tryxxx-like-methods-with-out-parameters-vs-returning-a-nullable-value-type)

Comment: @Beatles1692 Code the predates C#-2? Unless you're writing a 3rd party library, you shouldn't be concerned.

Comment: @DavidArno I don't see why `null` is evil. When properly handled and documented, I see nothing wrong with it. It's more error prone, yes, but that depends on the developer.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I refer you (a) to "Null References: The Billion Dollar Mistake" (http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare) and (b) the fact that `null` is completely counter-intuitive, as evidenced by the endless "what's this NullReferenceException mean?" asked by newbies on this site. `Null` is arguably the single biggest mistake ever made with programming language design.

Comment: @DavidArno I don't find it that hard to understand, and as a developer gains more experience they understand how to use it wisely. I've read that article, and still think it would be the way I'd do it. The fact that alot of newbies here post a "What do I get a NRE" is because they are too lazy to search what it means in google, that's not `null`s fault.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The problem with `null` is that it doesn't respect the contract that it advertises.  A null `string` isn't a `string` even though it says it is.  And that's why using the `Option<T>` approach is better, because in a well written library it won't let you use the value if the result is `null`.  I have written more about this if you're interested: https://github.com/louthy/language-ext

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant method is

```
int Parse(string value)
```

The Tryxxxx methods only exist for an implementation detail named performance. If you are seeking elegance you can use the Parse method and handle any errors by failing fast. 
You can instead return a tuple but this will cost an additional allocation on the heap since Tuple is a reference type.

A better solution in terms of performance (if you care) would be aKeyValuePair. But it hides (like tuple) the semantics behind generic data types which is not optimal for code clarity. A better way to signal failure than by defining some convention that the first bool of the tuple contains the failure state is by defining your own data type.

```
struct ParseResult<T>
{
    public bool Success { get; private set; }
    public T Value { get; private set; }

    public ParseResult(T value, bool success):this()
    {
        Value = value;
        Success = success;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static ParseResult<int> TryParse(string s)
    {
        int lret = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(s, out lret))
        {
            return new ParseResult<int>(lret, true);
        }
        else
        {
            return new ParseResult<int>(lret, false);
        }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string test = "1";
        var lret = TryParse(test);
        if( lret.Success )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", lret.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

That approach is still quite efficient and spares you the out parameters at the cost of the allocation of a cheap container object.

Comment: Downvote for suggesting that a method that throws an exception for completely unexceptional reasons, as `Parse` does, is anything other than utterly inelegant.

Comment: @Davide Arno: What is elegant depends on your personal style. Returning exceptions by value inside of a tuple is a clear violation of how exceptions are supposed to be used. If hope FXCop will not let your stylish checkin succeed.  Unstylish coding guidelines are there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the problem is that to follow the functional programming approach you should always provide a return value for an input value.  So the returning `void` route isn't the way to go.  You need to return a value that can represent success (and hold the successful result) and failure (and hold no result).

The closest to that is where you have returned a `Tuple` which includes the exception.  However you then don't have the 'infrastructure' to deal with the `Tuple` reliably once you've got it.  So the code scaffolding around it will be repeated.

Take a look at [this library](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) `language-ext`.  It deals with improving the `out` problem for `TryParse` using its implementation of `Option<T>`.

```
string inp = "123";

// Attempts to parse the value, uses 0 if it can't
int value1 = parseInt(inp).IfNone(0);

// Functional alternative to above
// Attempts to parse the value, uses 0 if it can't
int value2 = ifNone(parseInt(inp), 0);

// Attempts to parse the value and then pattern matches the result 
int value3 = parseInt(inp).Match(
                 Some: x  => x * 2,
                 None: () => 0
                 );

// Functional alternative to above
// Attempts to parse the value and then pattern matches the result
int value4 = match( parseInt(inp),
                 Some: x  => x * 2,
                 None: () => 0
                 );
```

The library also allows you to just check that something is valid:

```
if( parseInt(inp) )
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
```

And allows for comparisons without actually extracting the value:

```
if( parseInt(inp) == 123 )
    return 123;
else
    return 0;
```

As well as logical operations:

```
var allValid = parseInt(x) && parseInt(y) && parseInt(z);
var someValid = parseInt(x) || parseInt(y) || parseInt(z);
```

And finally LINQ expressions which can often remove the need for if-then-else or matching:

```
var res = from x in parseInt(inp1)
          from y in parseInt(inp2)
          from z in parseInt(inp3)
          select x + y + z;
```

It also has `TryGetValue` extensions for `IDictionary`, `IReadOnlyDictionary`, `IImmutableDictionary` and `IImmutableSet` that instead return `Option<T>` and can be used as above.